# Appcelerator - email validation on TextField

Tags: textfield, appcelerator, email-validation

What's the best method to check textfield input for email, using Appcelerator Studio?
Can I use regex or what?

Thanks,
Zoltan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use normal javascript to check for an email. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/5193915

and pass $.textfield.value into the function.